# Count number of vowels in a word and generate a report summary using SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to count number of vowels in a word. Is it possible to do it in SQL? I can easily implement it using a function(PL/SQL).

But I want it to be done in SQL.

I have no clue about how to start. To enhance my requirement, it is not just vowels. Just to count whatever alphabets list given. also To display the the number of occurences as well.

**Example** : `STACKOVERFLOW`

```
A 1
E 1
I 0
O 2
U 0
```

### Note on possible duplicate

The possible duplicate link you suggest just count the letters; in order to generate a report, that approach won't help! If you wish, please re-evaluate.

Comment: counting just vowels may be done, as you need the group as well, you have generate virtual rows. It should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT vowel_list.chr,
  COUNT(my_string.chr)
FROM
  (SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR('STACKOVERFLOW',level,1)) AS chr
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <=LENGTH('STACKOVERFLOW')
  ) my_string,
  (SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR('AEIOU',level,1)) AS chr
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <=LENGTH('AEIOU')
  ) vowel_list
WHERE vowel_list.chr = my_string.chr(+)
GROUP BY vowel_list.chr
ORDER BY 1;
```

`CONNECT BY level <= n` generates n virtual rows with level from 1,2... n

`SUBSTR()` extracts one character at a time, and finally the word is split into columns.

Outer join with the vowels word table, and you're done!

Comment: This is a very cumbersome and overcomplicated solution IMO

Comment: i find this is very simple and easy as my list is dynamic! Thanks @MaheswaranRavisankar again!! this helps much! let me try.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
with vowels as (
      select 'a' as c from dual union all
      select 'e' as c from dual union all
      select 'i' as c from dual union all
      select 'o' as c from dual union all
      select 'u' as c from dual
     )
select vowels.c,
       sum(length(replace(lower(val), vowels.c, 'xx')) - length(val))
from (select 'StackOverflow' as val from dual) t cross join
     vowels
group by vowels.c
order by vowels.c;
```

The count is managed by looking at the length of the string.  Each vowel is replaced by two characters, increasing the overall length of the string by one each time the vowel appears.